# Construction SQL using preg_replace?

Tags: php, sql

We are hitting an issue where we are using PHP to construct an SQL statement, and that is using the preg_replace function. Ive found the documentation [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

but I'm having trouble understanding what our pattern means (this is legacy code that I've never tinkered with before.)

```
static function buildQuery ($sql, $params)
{
error_log ("1");
error_log (print_r($params, true));

    foreach ((array) $params as $k => $v)
    {
        $v = pg_escape_string ($v);
    error_log ("2");
    error_log ($v);
        $sql = preg_replace ("/:$k(?=\W|$)/i", "'$v'", $sql);
    }

error_log ("3");
error_log ($sql);

    return $sql;
}
```

The issue we are trying to fix is that before the preg_replace line is called we have a value going into the statement that is "\ \test" with two backslashes (had to add the space for it to show up here). After that line the two backslashes has evaluated into "\test" and when that gets read into our client from the database it becomes a tab followed by "est" which is not what we want. I understand that the /i has to do with recognizing pretty much any case. the \W seems to be a meta-character to find a word? $k is the key i assume for that column of the table but the rest of it i don't understand, and I don't know why it would result in trimming a backslash.

I'm pretty much a beginner on this, I'll keep looking through the documentation and maybe something will dawn on me but I could use pointers on what this means, where I can find more information about it, and how I might fix this issue.

Thanks

EDIT its a postgres database, version 9.3 if that's relevant.

Comment: Why are there two backslashes in the data? And is this going to be a INSERT/UPDATE or SELECT?

Comment: It's going into an UPDATE or an INSERT call depending on whether theres an existing entry. I'm under the impression that there are two backslashes so our client can parse it back down to a single backslash correctly. We need user input to be able to include backslash characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "\t" is likely getting interpreted by PHP's string interpolation. You could try using a single-quoted string for the pattern (you'll need to concatenate the $k variable in) but if you're able to replace this with actual parameter binding it'd be safer and more reliable.

Here's [Regex101](https://regex101.com)'s explanation of that pattern, if it's any help:

```
/:test(?=\W|$)/i
:test matches the characters :test literally (case insensitive)
Positive Lookahead (?=\W|$)
Assert that the Regex below matches
1st Alternative \W
\W matches any non-word character (equal to [^a-zA-Z0-9_])
2nd Alternative $
$ asserts position at the end of the string, or before the line terminator
right at the end of the string (if any)

Global pattern flags
i modifier: insensitive. Case insensitive match (ignores case of [a-zA-Z])
```

Comment: Can I get some clarification on trying to use a single quoted string for the pattern? do you mean something like $sql = preg_replace ('/:'.'$k'.'(?=\W|$)/i', "'$v'", $sql);

I havent really gotten any version of this to work, it just sort of breaks everything, but I only sort of know what I'm doing.

The regex explanation is very helpful, I'm looking into it more now to see if i can find a better solution for what its doing

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I was getting at. I'm not totally sure it'll solve the problem, but "\t" becoming a tab definitely sounds like PHP is interpreting it. Just for context, using PDO and parameter binding (few examples in the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) would be the right way to solve this but it sounds like you'd be looking at some heavy refactoring.

Comment: I havent gotten it working but ill accept this as the right answer since I at least know a lot more about whats going on and where I can start looking. Thanks